# xpath selenium locating next sibling - any element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

The URL is [enter link description here](https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&bbn=1&rh=n%3A1%2Cp_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin%3A8622846011&dc&fs=true&ds=v1%3AgAO0%2BZc%2BC6RthRkqyWzOHmDVufv7JbuCK96Grvjle68&qid=1665559431&rnid=8622845011&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_eighteen_browse-bin_5)

Is there any way in selenium XPath to get value the element just the element which following sibling of located element

`//span[contains(text(),"by")]//following-sibling::a`

in this code I want to take the next element because sometimes it is not an anchor tag but span

For getting values of Author I am using the way, searching for "by" word element then

```py
x_authors=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//span[contains(text(),"by")]//following-sibling::a')    
x_authors_a=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//span[contains(text(),"by")]//following-sibling::span[1]')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you could make your question clearer if you could edit it and add code blocks showing examples of the relevant HTML, including the case where the element you want is an `a`, and the case where it's a `span`.

Comment: By the way, since `//` is shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, that makes your full XPath `//span[contains(text(),"by")]/descendant-or-self::node()/following-sibling::a` which selects any `a` elements which follow sibling elements which are either `span` elements containing 'by', or descendants of a `span` containing 'by'.

Comment: As you say, `//following-siblig::a` should give any element `span` or `a` ? But even in inspect mode it gives `//span[contains(text(),"by")]//following-sibling::a` only 10 there should be 16

Comment: isn't it possible to add "and or" as in contains(). Like, `//span[contains(text(),"by")]//following-sibling::a or following-sibling::span`

Comment: No; `following-sibling::a` can only return `a` elements and will never return a `span` element

Comment: If you want elements which are either following-sibling `span` or following-sibling `a`, you can use: `following-sibling::*[self::span | self::a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XPath will give exactly what you need:

```py
"//span[text()='by ']/following-sibling::*[1]"
```

There are several points to be improved in your initial XPath:

1. `//span[contains(text(),"by")]` matches more than 16 relevant elements.
2. `/following-sibling::*` selects **All** the following siblings, of any tag name. But this selects all the following siblings, not only **adjacent** following siblings. To make this precise `[1]` index added.

Comment: with your help, by this way, I could get the price tag value which was unable to get for two days, `get_attribute('textContent')` by using class attribute "a-offscreen" . Thanks